# ssl self signed certificate error - localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this course which is very interesting but I have some problem.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

I get certificate error but I understand why is this problem. This certificate should be connected to name of my computer. I don`t understand how he biuld this certificate and how edit this issue.

[image]

Here is important code. What I have to do to solve this problem with certificate name?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace LocalAccountsApp.Filters
{
    public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public int Port { get; set; }

        public RequireHttpsAttribute()
        {
            Port = 443;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;

            if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get || request.Method == HttpMethod.Head)
                {
                    var uri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
                    uri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
                    uri.Port = this.Port;

                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found;
                    response.Headers.Location = uri.Uri;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                }

                actionContext.Response = response;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue you want to solve? The red shield on browser?

Comment: I would like to change this place "create for: localhost". I would like to put there name of my computer but this certificate in my opinion is developed automatically and I want to override it.

Comment: Only way to have a valid certificate is to buy it. Don't matter about details of self signed certificates.

Comment: To generate new self signed certificates, you can use tools such as Jexus Manager, http://jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is correct. The certificate you're using was signed by itself, for the domain `localhost`. Since it's not signed by a trusted certificate root (such as Verisign, for example), your browser warns you that the certificate is not valid and therefore the site *may* be illegitimate.

The error should not be causing problems with functionality, and when you deploy to production, you should get a trusted certificate signed for the domain you're deploying to.

You're not going to get anyone to sign a certificate for the domain `localhost`, but if the error bothers you, you can add the certificate you're using to the list of trusted root certificates by using MMC, as described in [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: I think he built this certification in code and it`s possible to change this. Probably he take this information automatically do you know how override name localhost?

Comment: `localhost` is an alias to `[::1]`, which is the IP address that always points to the computer you're on. You can add another name for your local machine by editing [the hosts file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958812.aspx), however, that will not change the validity of your certificate.

Comment: The certificate is usually stored outside of the application code, in a configuration for the HTTP server you're using. [This TechNet article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315588) has information on changing the certificate you use; however, keep in mind that if you want any certificate you make yourself to be trusted, you need to add it to your local trusted certificate list.